# Google Compute VM Getting Error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a NodeJS script on a Google Compute VM that will regularly poll an external service, yet after a few requests the script starts to error out with:
`Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN site.to.poll site.to.poll:443`

Now and then it will recover for a few requests before erroring again. The requests will generally be happening at ~15 second intervals but an event every few minutes will run about 20 requests all in about one second.

I'm not sure if it's something quota related. I've tried to check quota limits but they all seem well above what I'm utilizing, and the VM is on a premium network tier.

Answer (score 0):

There are hard limits against API request rate in GCP and they are counted by the project (regardless of service account used).

The only methods that are exempt from the count are `*.get` and `*.list`.

> API rate limits define the number of requests that can be made to the
> Compute Engine API. API rate limits apply on a per-project basis. Rate
> limits are enforced at intervals of every 100 seconds. For example, 20
> requests/second would translate to 2000 requests within 100 seconds.
> That means that if you reach a specific limit anytime within 100
> seconds, you need to wait for your quota bucket to refresh to make
> more requests.

Have a look at the documentation to get exact numbers on [API rate limits](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits).